# Clear/Reset hover state in touch screen devices

Tags: javascript, ios, hover, touchscreen

Any suggestions on how i can reset/clear a hover state that is activated within a touch screen device like an ipad.

I have some tooltips that show on hover that's actually a click within the ipad due to how it deals with a hover.

But is there is a way to set it so the hover state gets reset to normal. As the problem is the tool tip won't re show as it still thinks it's being hovered.  Clicking on another tooltip, then back on it works.

Edit:
Very basic JSfiddle to demonstrate the issue, needs to be viewed within a ios device to see problem.

hover(click when in ipdad) the box will appear and then disappear.  Try hovering/clicking again and it won't re appear within a touch devices, unless you then hover/click on another tooltip and then back to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the tool tip is implemented, it might be a good idea to just put a timeout on it.  Then after 10 seconds or so it just hides and resets itself.  If you add your code we could help with a specific recommendation.

EDIT:

I added `mousedown` to your jquery events and it seems to work as you wish now on ipad.
See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqFDC/35/).

```
$('.tooltip').on('mouseenter mousedown', function(e){
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  Yeah i'm already applying a timeout, which works fine for hiding it.  But within that timeout i want to some how reset the hover as the ipad seems to keep the hover state on a click.  So that means you can't re hover again, unless you hover over another item.  I've added a very basic jsfiddle that demonstrate the issue when used within an ios device. http://jsfiddle.net/bennyb/kqFDC/34/

Comment: That makes sense now.  See my updated answer.  I think this is what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is a nice idea thanks, the only thing would be if someone was trying to have a tool tip hover and the click do something different, but then they are always going to run into ipad issues.  But this works for me, thanks again.